# Dynamically add or remove code module in a laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, content-management-system, laravel-livewire

I have been trying to understand how this concept works. Adding or removing code modules from laravel project. I have seen this feature in many places such as quickadminpanel.com, October CMS etc. These sites are used to create an admin panel quicker, there is an interesting feature that i found in quickadminpanel that is installing module that i need. Basically i want to achieve this but i don't know how to do !! May be someone can help as this feature and concept actually exists.

[image]

Comment: The systems you've mentioned are applications, which have built support for third-party packages (including definitions of what interfaces those packages must implement, hooks for them to register their callbacks, that sort of thing), and third parties have built such packages, following the rules defined by those applications. Laravel is a framework for building applications. You would be able to use it to build support for third-party packages in your application, but not all applications have the concept of a "customer", for example, so it's not possible to make this fully generic.

Comment: The example I mentioned in the description is a web application. I understand this can't be fully generic. Recently I was planning to start learning something new and this came into my mind. How this can be achieve ? Current I am working for a company they are building 8 platforms. these 8 platform has 35% similar features so in that case we are using another repository to pull the common features across all platform for consistency. Is this application using same concept ?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a common way to share functionality between similar platforms. It's the same sort of thing you're talking about, only a much lighter weight implementation, because it doesn't need to scale to thousands of plugins doing a myriad of different things, it just needs to explicitly support the things you're doing. And because you're writing the applications, you know exactly which repos you need, so there's no need for a fancy UI to control installing and enabling and disabling them.

Comment: Thank you so much for discussing. I mailed the author for help and luckily he replied. Now the concept is much clear to me. He simply replied this, "It's similar to how Laravel works with stubs - copy-pasting files as templates, replacing the variables in content: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWarTZuates&t=1s"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author himself replied in a mail. Now the concept is much clear to me. He simply replied this, "It's similar to how Laravel works with stubs - copy-pasting files as templates, replacing the variables in content: youtube.com/watch?v=eWarTZuates&t=1s"